# Video background is not playing on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, html5-video

I have a video which is used like a background one:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9 video_1">
<video  id="video"  autoplay="autoplay" playsinline loop name="media"><source src="../img/flowers.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
</div>
```

but my problem is that the video plays normaly on Android and web, but not on iOS devices..I have tried to add **playsinline, muted** but nothing worked..

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: are you using webview?

Comment: @imranRasheed no

Comment: okay so you can use the plyr.io its support all features which you want

Comment: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr here is the link to the Library and I also answered the below demo player

Answer (score 1):

**Playr.io Its support all features and background Playing**

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
<video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg" id="player">
                <!-- Video files -->
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="576">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="720">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1440p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1440">

                <!-- Caption files -->
                <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt"
                    default>
                <track kind="captions" label="Français" srclang="fr" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.fr.vtt">

                <!-- Fallback for browsers that don't support the <video> element -->
                <a href="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" download>Download</a>
            </video>
  
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn js-play">Play</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-pause">Pause</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-stop">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-rewind">Rewind</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-forward">Forward</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* This is purely for the demo */
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.plyr {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  // This is the bare minimum JavaScript. You can opt to pass no arguments to setup.
  const player = new Plyr('#player' , {
     fullscreen: {
        iosNative: true
    }
  });
  

  // Expose
  window.player = player;

  // Bind event listener
  function on(selector, type, callback) {
    document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(type, callback, false);
  }

  // Play
  on('.js-play', 'click', () => { 
    player.play();
  });

  // Pause
  on('.js-pause', 'click', () => { 
    player.pause();
  });

  // Stop
  on('.js-stop', 'click', () => { 
    player.stop();
  });

  // Rewind
  on('.js-rewind', 'click', () => { 
    player.rewind();
  });

  // Forward
  on('.js-forward', 'click', () => { 
    player.forward();
  });
});
```